# Foco na janela aberta

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou com uma aplicação em wpf, com vários botões que abrem outras janelas fora a do sistema principal.

Chamo elas através dos:

.Show();
.Focus();

Se o usuário clicar várias vezes no botão abria várias janelas, consertei isso colocando uma variável global que seta quando abre a janela e fecha.

O problema é que eu preciso focar na janela já aberta quando o usuário clica novamente no botão, pois a janela já está aberta, junto com a principal.

Comment: Que tal fazer o *disable* do botão após este ser clicado e ter aberto a nova janela com sucesso?

Comment: ramaral não posso fazer isso, a minha tarefa fala para dar um foco na janela aberta, mas não consigo.

Comment: Quantas janelas do mesmo tipo pode ter abertas? Pelo que entendi cada botão abre um tipo de janela, certo?.

Comment: Sim cada botão abre uma janela diferente, o que preciso fazer é trazer pra frente de todas a janela que foi solicitada no botão, entendeu?

Comment: Não sei se entendi. Porque, se cada botão abre apenas um tipo de janela e só pode haver uma janela de cada tipo aberta, basta, ao clicar novamente no botão, fazer `janela.setFocus()`. Se você postasse algum código seria mais fácil ajudar!

Comment: Usuario_Consultar frmGo = new Usuario_Consultar();

            if (util.Funcoes.is_open_window != 1)
            {
                util.Funcoes.is_open_window = 1;
                frmGo.Show();
                frmGo.Focus();
            }

Comment: Essa é a função de aperto do botão, quando ele aperta há uma instância do objeto da janela que é declarada. Depois há um if que pergunta se a variável global que controla as janelas foi setada para não haver mais de uma janela, entrando no if ele abre a janela e dá o foco nela.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21601/discussion-between-jp-almeida-and-ramaral).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi `util.Funcoes.is_open_window == 1` indica que a janela está aberta. Assim sendo, acrescente um `else` à sua condição e faça com que a janela receba o *focus*:

```
Usuario_Consultar frmGo = new Usuario_Consultar();
if (util.Funcoes.is_open_window != 1) //Abre a janela
{ 
    util.Funcoes.is_open_window = 1; 
    frmGo.Show(); 
    frmGo.Focus(); 
}
else //A janela está aberta recebe o focus
{
    frmGo.Activate();
}
```

Por que não declara `util.Funcoes.is_open_window` como `bool`? Tornaria o código mais fácil de ler.

Comment: Eu tentei isso mas não sei porque ele não foca, não faz nada entendeu?

Comment: Eu estava instanciando o objeto de novo quando apertava o botão, só foi colocá-lo como global e setá-lo como null.

Comment: Eu estava a considerar que `frmGo`fosse global. Que `Usuario_Consultar frmGo = new Usuario_Consultar();` estivesse fora do método do click do botão

Comment: Obrigado ramaral, coloquei como sua resposta a correta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava instanciando o objeto de novo quando apertava o botão, só foi colocá-lo como global e setá-lo como null e quando instanciava ele ficava diferente de null, assim era só perguntar se era diferente de null para focá-lo.